# How to change and(&) operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

as we know & operator used for reference and returning address of a variable. What I want to do is change the operator syntax to something like _ or | (You got the point). How can I do that?

The default:

```
int *p;
int a;
p = &a;
```

What I want to do:

```
int *p;
int a;
p = _a; // or |a
```

Comment: Just use `std::adressof()`

Comment: Usually with questions like this, you don't just need the "I want to", you also need the "**Why** I want to". Because if you are looking to play around the with the language the simple answer is "No you cant do this" and the reason is because it would not be useful and it would be complex to implement.

Comment: If you are successful, you will confuse the hell out of people that would read your code.  *"Speaking words of wisdom, let it be."*

Comment: Technically that's not called the "and" operator. It's the [address-of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) operator

Comment: @BenJones: To be fair, it's alternative name is `bitand`. As in `int* p = bitand a;`

Comment: @MSalters the `bitand` is an entirely different operation (binary operation defined for integral types.)  Can you really use it in that way?

Comment: @BenJones: Yes. And `Foo::compl Foo()` is a destructor. ( `~` is `compl`, also outside operator context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

& is 'and' when applied to TWO operators, but it is 'take address' when applied unary. You can't possibly confuse them.

If you are just curious you can do this

```
#include <iostream>
#define _ &


int main()
{
   int a = 5;
   int* p_a = _ a;
   std::cout << *p_a << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

You have to put a space here. And believe me, nobody wants you redefining standard operators.

Comment: It compiles, I checked

Comment: But now, you no longer can do `int _ = 42;`.

Comment: ͏+͏1͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ And I'm pretty sure the behaviour is well-defined although this way is *very* disruptive.

Comment: True, _ can be a name of a variable. Though you can use some other symbol. I still believe it is foolish to redefine standards. They are bad as it is, nobody needs you to make them even worse :D

Answer (score 6):

You can't change to `_` since that's not an operator, so therefore cannot be overloaded.

You can't change to `|` since the *airity* of that operator is binary, whereas pointer dereference `*` is unary.

Even if you do pick an operator with the correct airity for overloading, note that you *cannot* overload a built-in type such as `int`.

Finally if you want to see operator overloading at its most powerful, take a look at this project: http://boost-spirit.com/home/ where expression templates, coupled with operator overloading, are used to mimic EBNF grammars.

Comment: So I cant change the & operator syntax to anything else?

Comment: Plus operators cannot be overloaded for embedded types

Comment: Basically you can't create new operators.

Comment: @StelTeam legaly no. You can write your own preprocessor, that will do that, but I doubt there is any value in it.

Comment: @StelTeam You can for user-created types, as long as that "anything else" is a unary operator like `+`, `-`, or `*`, although you really shouldn't do that as it would be very confusing to anyone else reading your program.

Answer (score 1):

As [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51403128/3233393) already answered, you cannot replace operators that easily.

If, however, you really can't stand to use `&` as an address-of operator, you *can* use the [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) function. It will still be weird and unidiomatic, but at least it makes syntactic sense.